# How to show Bootstrap Alert on Button Click via Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a registration form page created on asp.net.

When the user click **Submit** button i want to show a Bootstrap alert message at the top of the page for 5 sec that say **"Registered Successfully""**.

If the user click **Submit** and the user has not fill the required fields it should not show the alert message until he fill all the fields and submit.

I've tried the following code but nothing happen after filling all the fields and submit.

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head runat="server">
 <link href="Styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
            <div class="container">

            <div id="messages" class="hide" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <div id="messages_content"></div>
            </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="form">
            <label for="FN">
                <br />
                <br />
                First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtFirstname" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="LN">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtLastname" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <br />
            Password<span style="color: red">*</span>:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <label for="BT">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Pw" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="Please Provide a password !">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
            E-mail<span style="color: red">*</span>:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" TextMode="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EM" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Please Provide an Email">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrTable" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <label for="BT">Blood Type:</label>
            <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" Skin="Telerik">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="1" Text="A+" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="2" Text="A-" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="3" Text="B+" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="4" Text="O" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="5" Text="O+" />
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
 <button class="btn btn-default"  id="btnSubmit" onclick="insertData()">Submit</button>
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Cancel" />
    </form>
                </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#form').submit(function(e) {
                $('#messages').removeClass('hide').addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible').slideDown().show();
                $('#messages_content').html('<h4>registration successful message </h4>');
                $('#modal').modal('show');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //insertData();
        fill_table();

    })
    function insertData() {
        var firstname = document.getElementById("txtFirstname").value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("txtLastname").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;

        if (firstname == "") {
            alert("fails");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                url: "Home.aspx/test",
                data: "{firstname: '" + firstname + "',lastname: '" + lastname + "', email: '" + email + "' , password: '" + password + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (resdata) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `<form id="form1" ...>` vs. `$('#form').submit(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div id="messages" class="hidden" >
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <div id="messages_content"></div>
            </div>

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                url: "Home.aspx/test",
                data: "{firstname: '" + firstname + "',lastname: '" + lastname + "', email: '" + email + "' , password: '" + password + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (resdata) {
                   $('#messages').removeClass('hidden').addClass('alert alert-success ');
                $('#messages_content').html('registration successful message ');
               } 
});
```

Comment: Please check this once@SmithBZ

Comment: Even with this one the alter message after submission disappear fast... its weird

Comment: are you reloading the same page after success? . If you can share the the actual code & API.. I can look into the issue

Comment: Nope, everytime i debug the page to test it again. So from the first time it disappear so fast.

Comment: Take a look here: https://pastebin.com/p6jH02uS the full code of the page @Ronanki Viswanadham

Comment: Any news ? @Ronanki Viswanadham

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger float-right" onclick="return confirmDel();"><i class="fa fa-remove mr-5"></i> Firma Sil</button>


<script language="javascript">
    function confirmDel() {
        var agree = confirm("Are you sure you can delete this company?\nBu işlem geri alınamaz!");
        if (agree) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Enes! I tested your code but what i need is to show the **Alert Message** using the Bootstrap Alerts design not the default one. And in your code only the button is designed using BS4 not the alert message.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add the message alert enable script on the ajax success method as below

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                url: "Home.aspx/test",
                data: "{firstname: '" + firstname + "',lastname: '" + lastname + "', email: '" + email + "' , password: '" + password + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (resdata) {
  $('#messages').removeClass('hide').addClass('alert alert-success ').slideDown().show();
```

$('#messages_content').html('registration successful message ');
                    }
                });

Comment: Hello @Ronanki Viswanadham ! Oh that was my mistake i was adding the script outside the ajax success. But the problem when i click submit now the message appear and disappear so fast i can't try to read. How can i add a time to this message to appear like for 5 sec.

Comment: The updated code is not showing the alert message anymore and nothing happen after i click on submit @Ronanki Viswanadham

Comment: try the above updated code.. old code work by removing the dismissable class i think

Comment: I tried the updated code by the alert message keep disappearing so fast. Also i removed the dismissable class and i try it with timeout function nothing happens.And thank you for following up my issue...  @ Ronanki Viswanadham